# Who is this statue of?

Tags: europe, identification, hungary

[image]

Purchased it from an Italian leather shop in Budapest Hungary. Curious to find out the history behind it. I was recently informed it may be of a Hungarian cowboy. His outfit looks a bit formal. It does not have any markings or stamps. The shop keep told me it was for keys but that was about the extent of her English speaking skills.

Comment: Why do you say 'possibly German'?

Comment: Just a guess. That’s what bought me here.

Comment: Can you explain why you are assuming that it represents anyone in particular? And, given where you bought it, why you don't think it could be a Hungarian? It looks like a [Hungarian cowboy](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-hungary-kalocsa-traditional-hungarian-cowboy-at-bakodpuszta-equesdtrian-36710161.html).

Comment: Are there any markings on the bottom or back. And what is its purpose? What type of shop?

Comment: It is an Italian Leather shop that sells belts , bags , bull whips. No reason in particular I’m just assuming it’s someone or represents something historical. No markings whatsoever. The shop owner did not speak any English. The shop was in Budapest Hungary.

Comment: Please use the edit function and add this information into your question. It would seem, from the location that @DenisdeBernardy might be on track with his suggestion of a cowboy...

Comment: Could you specify where this shop exactly was, and maybe its name?

Comment: It can be a key holder (you put it on the wall to hang key rings). And I agree with others, it looks very much like a Hungarian cowboy. The cloth style doesn’t match to nobility’s.

Answer (score 9):

It's a generic Hungarian cowboy wearing a traditional [Szűr](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sz%C5%B1r_(ruh%C3%A1zat)), rather than anyone in particular.

[image: Hungarian cowboy]

(h/t JustCal for this specific image.)

I checked whether it might [Széchenyi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istv%C3%A1n_Sz%C3%A9chenyi), [Batthyány](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lajos_Batthy%C3%A1ny), [Kossuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lajos_Kossuth), or one of the other Hungarian leaders who regularly pop up as place names. The beard style matches none of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect an individual to that statue, I'd check one of the "betyár"s (outlaws similar to Robin Hood). Both of the most famous ones are depicted similarly: [Rózsa Sándor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1ndor_R%C3%B3zsa) and [Sobri Jóska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3ska_Sobri) (in eastern name order).

The figure is not detailed enough to decide if it's someone in particular or just a guy in a traditional outfit.